# How to publish WCF web service (created in CodeGear Delphi for .NET) on IIS?

Tags: wcf, delphi, iis

I succeeded to create WCF web service in CodeGear Delphi for .NET 2007/2009.

I use this tutorial:
https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/building-net-35-wcf-restful-web-services-with-delphi-2007-38508

In this article they created console application and tested web service in it.

But i need to publish this WCF web service on IIS - how can I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to make dll (not console app) and my work looks like this:

**1) unit uServiceIntf.pas**

```
unit uServiceIntf;

interface

uses
  System.ServiceModel,
  System.ServiceModel.Web;

type
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = 'http://localhost:3000/')]
  IService = interface
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate='Add?a={x}&b={y}')]
    function Add(x, y: integer): integer;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

**2) unit uServiceImpl.pas**

```
unit uServiceImpl;

interface

uses
  uServiceIntf;

type
  TService = class(TObject, IService)
  public
    function Add(x, y: integer): integer;
  end;

implementation

{ TService }

function TService.Add(x, y: integer): integer;
begin
  Result := x + y;
end;

end.
```

**3) DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.dpr**

```
library DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll;

uses
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  System.Reflection,
  System.Runtime.InteropServices,
  uServiceImpl in 'uServiceImpl.pas',
  uServiceIntf in 'uServiceIntf.pas';

[assembly: AssemblyTitle('')]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription('')]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration('')]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany('')]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct('')]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright('')]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark('')]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture('')]

[assembly: AssemblyVersion('1.0.*')]

[assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false)]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile('')]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyName('')]

[assembly: ComVisible(False)]

begin
end.
```

**4) DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.svc:**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.TService" %>
```

**5) web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
      <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="returnFaults">
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
           <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
     <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="returnFaults" name="DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.TService">
          <endpoint address="Add" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService">
          </endpoint>
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:3000/DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.svc"/>
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
      <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**6) Publish on IIS:**

I put svc-file and web.config file in folder D:\MySite and dll-file in folder D:\MySite\bin.

I give all rights to folder D:\MySite for user IIS_IUSRS.

I make a site:

[image]

**7) Result:**
I try this in Chrome browser:

a) http://localhost:3000/Add?a=2&b=3

b) http://localhost:3000/DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.svc/Add?a=2&b=3

Both don't work.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What have you tried so far, what succeeded and what is the exact blocker that you face?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, i've read this article and followed all steps in it - got a console application with wcf web service inside - now i can use this web service in browser like this: http://localhost:8000/Add?a=2&b=3 But how can i publish it on IIS?

Comment: Serg, is IIS running on your own machine or a remote server?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad,on my own machine

Answer (score 0):

Read this page: https://www.ojdevelops.com/2017/10/deploying-web-application-to-local-iis.html

It says the steps are as follows:

[image]

Besides that, if you want to have a specific URL that's not related to localhost, then add the URL you desire to be local to hosts, mapped to 127.0.0.1. In that case you will also need to set the host headers at IIS, see: https://docs.revenera.com/isxhelp23/helplibrary/IISHostHeader.htm

Comment: Thank you, but i have only one exe-file - console application. But for IIS i need 3 files: dll, svc, web.config - how can i generate this 3 files in CodeGear Delphi for .NET?

Comment: @SergS honestly, I don't know. My answer deals with IIS hosting in general, but I have not much experience in Delphi. Nevertheless, I try to help. Maybe this page helps: https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/36962

Comment: this article is very similar to the article from my question - i already have found it yesterday - and there is no information about IIS publishing in it too

Comment: @SergS sorry about that. I know no more than you about this specific issue. I think my answer is correct, but it misses a needed detail. Maybe this link is helpful: https://www.drbob42.com/examines/examinB4.htm ?

Comment: and this article is also read by me yestarday - and it's also not helpful - it's about Delphi Prism wich is different from CodeGear Delphi for .NET

Comment: @SergS I'm afraid I do not know the answer and I have no means to test it at this point. Please let me know if the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start by looking at [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis),  which will guide you through the hosting service step by step.

Comment: thank you, i've folowed the steps from this article, but haven't succeed - i corrected my main answer - described all my work - can you look at it?

Comment: Are there any error messages during deployment, and make sure your port is not occupied.

Comment: there are no error messages during deployment, port is not occupied. Maybe DelphiRESTBasicSample_Service_dll.svc or web.config are wrong?